# How can we slow down the opening of mat-expansion panel using angular-animations and give them a fade in out effect

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-animations

How can I animate mat-expansion panel on open and close.

```
trigger('fadeInOut', [
      state('open', style({
        opacity:1
      })),
      state('closed', style({
        opacity:0
      })),
      transition('open=>closed', animate('1.5s ease-out')),
      transition('closed=>open', animate('1.5s ease-out'))
]),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently doesn't seem to be possible to alter Angular Material's animations for the components ([GitHub issue for feature request](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8857)). However there is hack proposed by the user [omieliekh in GitHub](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8857#issuecomment-401793529). Applied to the MatExpasionPanel component looks like this:

```
    import {
      animate,
      animateChild,
      group,
      state,
      style,
      transition,
      trigger,
      query,
      AnimationTriggerMetadata,
    } from '@angular/animations';
```

```
const EXPANSION_PANEL_ANIMATION_TIMING = '10000ms cubic-bezier(0.4,0.0,0.2,1)';
MatExpansionPanel['decorators'][0].args[0].animations = [
  trigger('bodyExpansion', [
    state('collapsed, void', style({ height: '0px', visibility: 'hidden' })),
    state('expanded', style({ height: '*', visibility: 'visible' })),
    transition('expanded <=> collapsed, void => collapsed',
      animate(EXPANSION_PANEL_ANIMATION_TIMING)),
  ])];
```

You can see it working in this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/slowdown-mat-expansion-animation).

**[Be aware that this hack does no seem to work in production mode](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8857#issuecomment-404702251)**.

Comment: Is there any other way that we can slow down as it would be failing in production made

Comment: Maybe using webpack to find and replace `'EXPANSION_PANEL_ANIMATION_TIMING = '10000ms cubic-bezier(0.4,0.0,0.2,1)';` with the desired animation timing